# How to apply resampling and grouping at the same time with Pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, indexing, group-by, resampling

My objective is to add rows in pandas in order to replace missing data with previous data and resample dates at the same time. 
My Data contains different products IDs and I must do a groupBy each time because I must keep the time serie data of every productId.
Example :
This is my dataframe :

```
   productId    popularity  converted_timestamp     date
0     1            5         2015-12-01           2015-12-01
1     1            8         2015-12-02           2015-12-02
2     1            6         2015-12-04           2015-12-04
3     1            9         2015-12-07           2015-12-07
4     2            5         2015-12-01           2015-12-01
5     2           10         2015-12-03           2015-12-03
6     2            6         2015-12-04           2015-12-04
7     2           12         2015-12-07           2015-12-07
8     2           11         2015-12-09           2015-12-09
```

And this is what I want :

```
      date     productId  popularity    converted_timestamp
0   2015-12-01    1          5          2015-12-01
1   2015-12-02    1          8          2015-12-02
2   2015-12-03    1          8          2015-12-02
3   2015-12-04    1          6          2015-12-04
4   2015-12-05    1          6          2015-12-04
5   2015-12-06    1          6          2015-12-04
6   2015-12-07    1          9          2015-12-07
7   2015-12-01    2          5          2015-12-01
8   2015-12-02    2          5          2015-12-01
9   2015-12-03    2         10          2015-12-03
10  2015-12-04    2          6          2015-12-04
11  2015-12-05    2          6          2015-12-04
12  2015-12-06    2          6          2015-12-04
13  2015-12-07    2         12          2015-12-07
14  2015-12-08    2         12          2015-12-07
15  2015-12-09    2         11          2015-12-09
```

And this is my code :

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('productId', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.resample('D').ffill()).reset_index()
```

It works and it's perfect !
So my new Data looks like this :

```
           productId    popularity  converted_timestamp    date
11960909    15620743.0  526888.0    2016-01-11          2016-01-11
11960910    15620743.0  487450.0    2016-02-26          2016-02-26
11960911    15620743.0  487450.0    2016-02-26          2016-02-26
12355593    17175984.0  751990.0    2016-01-28          2016-01-28
12355594    17175984.0  584549.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355595    17175984.0  587289.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355596    17175984.0  574454.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355597    17175984.0  570663.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355598    17175984.0  566914.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355599    17175984.0  591241.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355600    17175984.0  590637.0    2016-01-26          2016-01-26
12355601    17175984.0  556794.0    2016-01-27          2016-01-27
12355602    17175984.0  512403.0    2016-02-10          2016-02-10
12355603    17175984.0  510561.0    2016-02-10          2016-02-10
12355604    17175984.0  513907.0    2016-02-10          2016-02-10
12355605    17175984.0  512403.0    2016-02-10          2016-02-10
12355606    17175984.0  511038.0    2016-02-10          2016-02-10
12355607    17175984.0  510561.0    2016-02-10          2016-02-10
12355608    17175984.0  554359.0    2016-01-27          2016-01-27
17028384    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028385    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028386    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028387    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028388    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028389    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028390    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028391    16013607.0  563480.0    2016-02-21          2016-02-21
17028392    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028393    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028394    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028395    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028396    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028397    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028398    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
17028399    16013607.0  546230.0    2016-02-14          2016-02-14
```

The same code gives this error message : 
**ValueError: cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit**

Why ? Help ? 
Thank you.

Comment: There is problem with duplicates - in some `group` you have duplicate `dates`.

Comment: You can simulate it very easy - change first date in sample from `2015-12-01` to `2015-12-02`

Comment: I see jezrael ! you're right ! Thank you ! There is no way to do this with duplicates ? Otherwise, I will try to have a median (for exemple) of duplicates values and apply the code. Thank you again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are duplicates - one possible solution:

```
df = df.groupby(['productId','converted_timestamp','date'], as_index=False)['popularity']
       .mean()
print (df)
    productId converted_timestamp       date     popularity
0  15620743.0          2016-01-11 2016-01-11  526888.000000
1  15620743.0          2016-02-26 2016-02-26  487450.000000
2  16013607.0          2016-02-14 2016-02-14  546230.000000
3  16013607.0          2016-02-21 2016-02-21  563480.000000
4  17175984.0          2016-01-26 2016-01-26  580821.000000
5  17175984.0          2016-01-27 2016-01-27  555576.500000
6  17175984.0          2016-01-28 2016-01-28  751990.000000
7  17175984.0          2016-02-10 2016-02-10  511812.166667
```

And then you can use (`pandas 0.18.1`):

```
df = df.set_index('date')
       .groupby('productId', group_keys=False)
       .resample('D')
       .ffill()
       .reset_index()
```